# Vue.js - how to use element menu dropdown

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm new to Vue.

I'm trying to use dropdown menu element.

```
  <el-dropdown trigger="click">
     <span class="el-dropdown-link">
        <i class="el-icon-more" />
      </span>
     <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
         <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-edit" @click="dialogFormVisible = true">Edit</el-dropdown-item>
         <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-circle-delete" @click="dialogVisible = true">Delete</el-dropdown-item>
     </el-dropdown-menu>
   </el-dropdown>
```

I want to display an Edit button and a Delete button. For some reason when i click on the icon nothing happens.
How do I make it active to display these buttons?

Answer (score 2):

It won't work directly you'll have to make use of command.

```
  <el-dropdown trigger="click" @command="handleCommand">
     <span class="el-dropdown-link">
        <i class="el-icon-more" />
     </span>
     <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
        <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-edit" command="a">Edit</el-dropdown-item>
        <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-circle-delete" command="b">Delete</el-dropdown-item>
     </el-dropdown-menu>
  </el-dropdown>
```

Then define handleCommand as follows

```
handleCommand(command) {
   if (command === 'a') {
      this.dialogFormVisible = true;
   }
   if (command === 'b') {
      this.dialogVisible = true;
   }
}
```

You can learn more about it here https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dropdown#dropdown

Answer (score 1):

use @click.native="" on the el-dropdown-item
eg:

```
<el-dropdown-item @click.native="dialogVisible = true">Delete</el-dropdown-item>
```